# C++ Character Arrays in Linked Lists

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, character, structure

I'm doing a linked list in C++ with two variables in a structure.  When I print the list, my code repeats the last item, even though I typed in a different item.

Input:

```
Black Duck
58
Green Hen
33
```

Output looks like this: ( I don't want this to happen)

```
Green Hen 58
Green Hen 33
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
char* item;
int count;
node *link;
 };

//global variable

node * HeadPointer = NULL;

//function prototypes

void Print (node *);
void newItem(char*, int, node *);
int main(){

char InitItem[50] = "\0";
int InitCount = 0;

node * CurrentRecordPointer = NULL;
char NextChar= '\0';
char ContinuationFlag = 'Y';

while(toupper(ContinuationFlag) == 'Y'){
    cout << "Enter the description of Item: " <<endl;
    NextChar = cin.peek();
    if (NextChar =='\n') {
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cin.get(InitItem, 49);
    cout<<"How many: "<<endl;
    cin>>InitCount;

    CurrentRecordPointer = new node;
    newItem(InitItem, InitCount, CurrentRecordPointer);
    HeadPointer = CurrentRecordPointer;

    cout <<"Do you want to enter more items?" <<endl;
    cout <<"Enter 'Y' or 'N'" <<endl;
    cin  >> ContinuationFlag;
        }

 Print(HeadPointer);
return 0;
  }

//functions

void newItem (char* InitItem, int InitCount, node *CurrentRecordPointer)    {

CurrentRecordPointer->item = InitItem;
CurrentRecordPointer->count = InitCount;
CurrentRecordPointer->link = HeadPointer;
```

}

```
void Print (node * Head)
{
while(Head !=NULL) {
cout<< Head->item<<" " << Head->count <<endl;
Head = Head -> link;
   }
 }
```

I want the output to looks like this:

```
Black Duck 
58
Green Hen
33
```

I know it's my usage of pointers.  I just don't know what to replace it with.  If someone could help me figure this out, would appreciate it.

Comment: What is the code for newItem?

Comment: void newItem (char* InitItem, int InitCount, node *CurrentRecordPointer)    {

CurrentRecordPointer->item = InitItem;
CurrentRecordPointer->count = InitCount;
CurrentRecordPointer->link = HeadPointer;
}<br> That's the function. It has been called in the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because all your nodes share the same item. You have only one copy of InitItem. So when you cin it, all your nodes point to this string, and display it.

Try with dynamically creating a new item for each node in your while loop :

```
...
char * InitItem = new char(50);
cin.get(InitItem, 49);
...
```

Comment: will this be considered a global variable or something inside the main?

Comment: you don't want to make it global since you need one `char*` for each `node`. you have to create one for every `node` you create. You could also delegate the creation of the `new char*` to `void newItem()` if you want to keep you variable newItem.